# How can I remove an override check button in TYPO3 TCA

Tags: typo3

Servus,
I am searching for the solution how can I remove an override check button in TYPO3 TCA.[image]

My TCA configuration:

```
'myfield' => array(
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'exclude'   => 1,
    'label'     => 'my field',
    'config'    => array(
        'type'        => 'input',
        'size'        => '20',
        'eval'        => 'trim',
        'placeholder' => 'my placeholder',
    )
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a problem with your placeholder. If you dont need your placeholder, you can remove it.

So your code can look like this:

```
'myfield' => array(
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'exclude'   => 1,
    'label'     => 'my field',
    'config'    => array(
        'type'        => 'input',
        'size'        => '20',
        'eval'        => 'trim',
    )
),
```

so after that this should looks like this:
[image]